# How can I divide per data of column CountOfVendor into Textfield TotalCountVendor and display in another dgv. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

[How can I divide each per row into Total Count Vendor and Display in another datagridview column which is QAallocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXiA.png)

How can I divide each data of `CountOfVendor` into textfield `TotalCountVendor` and display into another datagridview column which is QAallocation. 
help me please

Code
[image]

UI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selected row of datagridview you can set:

```
txtCountofVentor.text = dgvventor1.currentrow.cell(1).value
txtTotalCountVentor.text = dgvventor2.currentrow.cell(1).value
```